# wpf dependency with ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to display value of selected RibbonMenuButton in TextBlock below. Items of ribbonMenuButton are defined as ItemTemplate. How to define reference in Path? I marked it by "xxx"

```
<ribbon:RibbonMenuButton ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=CompaniesList.Companies}" x:Name="rbtnCompanies" Label="{x:Static resources:ConsoliaJPK.SELECT_COMPANY}" SmallImageSource="Resources/Images/Check32.png" Margin="16,0,-15.604,-0.264">
    <RibbonMenuButton.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tblCompany" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="tblCompany_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" >                                        
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </RibbonMenuButton.ItemTemplate>
</ribbon:RibbonMenuButton>
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding  ElementName=rbtnCompanies, Path=xxx}" Margin="41,6,-132,-6.604"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: I don't know much about that Ribbon stuff but aren't you supposed to use a `RibbonGallery` like described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonmenubutton?view=netframework-4.7.2?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `rbtnCompanies.xxx` should contain `Name`. You can do this assignment in your `tblCompany_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` I suppose.

Comment: Unfortunately it not works. Generally I need to display in  textblock current selected value of RibbonMenuButton.